# Update object value in useState array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently struggling with changing a couple of states that I currently have in my web app. The state is as follows:

```
const [points, setPoint] = useState([]);
```

Which stores the data like this:

```
0: (2) [{…}, {…}]
1: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

In other words, the array contains each an array of two objects. The content looks like this;

```
0:
elementId: 0
elementPosX: 615
elementPosY: 171
1:
elementId: "liiMJzWgphZPbnx"
elementPosX: 618.5
elementPosY: 317
```

I want to search if `x` is equal to the `elementId`, and then change the values directly linked to this object. How can I achieve this?

I have found a way to edit an object in a regular single array of objects like so:

```
setPoint(singlePoint.map(x => {
  if (x.id !== id) return x
  return { ...x, position: { x: xPosition - 365, y: yPosition - 80 } }
}))
```

This works, but I'm not sure if there is an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Your current approach is one of the best ways to do it. I'd stick with it.

Comment: Can you post what `singlePoint` looks like ?
From that code, you can at least make your callback more concise to
`setPoint(singlePoint.map(x => (x.id === id  ? {...x, position: {x: xPosition - 365, y: yPosition - 80}}  : x )));` (sorry for formatting)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay, thanks. However, how would I approach the editing of the first case, where I have another nested array?

Comment: Another possibility if you are working with very nested data is to use: [useImmer](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer) which will allow you to modify your data as if you are mutating it, which helps a lot with complicated data.

Comment: @aquinq Updated now, it's just a setter (hooks). I'm sorry if my question was vague, but I'm currently wondering about how I can edit the array of array of objects [?]

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the array order. You have first to find the element index and then update it:

```
setPoint((allPoints) => {
  const index = allPoint.findIndex((element) => element.id === x.id);
  allPoints[index] = {
    ...x,
    position: { x: xPosition - 365, y: yPosition - 80 },
  };
  return allPoints;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however - I still haven't managed to figure it out yet. I'm creating a new post now, with an in-depth description of my problem, with detailed information that hopefully can be of help.